# how to print two messages in single dialogue box using python?

Tags: python, messagebox

D= dict[a= 2, b=4, c=1, d=3]

I am using the above dictionary after sorting (ascending order) and displaying the sorted value along with the lowest value.

Desired output in the dialogue box

```
c=1
a=2
d=3
b=4

c lowest value is 1
```

I am trying the following code:

```
D dict[a= 2, b=4, c=1, d=3]
f= sorted(D.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
g= f[0]
f= [str(x) for x in f]
g= [str(x) for x in g]
msg= '\n'.join(f) + 'lowest value is\n'.join(g)
dlg= wx.MessageDialog(self,msg,"lowest value",wx.OK)
dlg.showModal()
dlg.Destroy()
```

using this we are getting:

```
(c=1)
(a=2)
(d=3)
(b=4)c
lowest value is 1
```

we do not want 'c' after b=4 instead we want 'c' in the next line as in desired output.
please help...

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure that code doesn't give that output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert extra newline characters:

```
msg = '\n'.join(f) + '\n\n' + ' lowest value is '.join(g) + '\n'
```

although the last line would be more logically built as:

```
msg = '\n'.join(f) + '\n\n%s lowest value is %s\n' % tuple(g)
```

And how about your dictionary definition?

```
D dict[a= 2, b=4, c=1, d=3]
```

was meant as

```
D = {'a': 2, 'b':4, 'c':1, 'd':3}
```

?

Comment: Would the itemgetter even work with a numeric index? If I had to guess, I'd say `D = [('a',2),('b',4),('c',1),('d',3)]` was the intent... EDIT: n/m, missed the `.items()` call.

Comment: `dict()` takes keyword arguments. `D = dict(a=2, b=4, c=1, d=3)` is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

Change msg to

```
>>> msg = '\n'.join(map(str,f)) + "\n\n{0} lowest value is {1}".format(g[0],g[1])
```

This will output:

```
>>> print msg
('c', 1)
('a', 2)
('d', 3)
('b', 4)

c lowest value is 1
```

Alternatively, if you want your code to output c=1,a=1 etc change msg a little bit:

```
>>> msg = '\n'.join(map(lambda x: str(x[0]) + "=" + 
    str(x[1]),f)) + "\n\n{0} lowest `value is {1}".format(g[0],g[1])`
```

This will output:

```
>>> print msg
c=1
a=2
d=3
b=4

c lowest value is 1
```